# Azure Data Factory V2: How to pass a file name to stored procedure variable

Tags: sql, azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

I have a big fact Azure SQL table with the following structure:

```
Company     Revenue
-------------------
A              100
B              200
C              100
.               .
.               .
.               .
```

I am now building a stored procedure on Azure Data Factory V2 that will delete all records of a special company from the Azure SQL fact table above in a monthly basis. For this exercise this special company shall be identified by the variable @company. The structure of the stored procedure was created as:

```
@company NVARCHAR(5)

DELETE FROM table 
WHERE [company] = @company
```

As I will have different Excel files from each company that will be inserting data into this table in a monthly basis (with Copy Activity), I want to use the stored procedure above to delete the old data from that company before I add the most updated one.

I would like then to pass to the variable "@company" the name of that Excel file (stored in a blob container) so that the stored procedure knows what is the relevant data to be deleted from the fact table. For example: If the Excel file is "A", the stored procedure shall be "delete from table where company = A".

Any ideas on how to pass the Excel file names to the variable "@company" and set this up on Azure Data Factory V2?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to pass the Excel file names to the variable
> "@company" and set this up on Azure Data Factory V2?

Based on your description, I found [Event-based trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#event-based-trigger) in azure data factory maybe will meet your needs. Event-based trigger runs pipelines in response to an event, such as the arrival of a file, or the deletion of a file, in Azure Blob Storage.

So, when the new excel file created in the blob storage (BTW, it only supports V2 storage account,more details please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger#data-factory-ui)), you could get the `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName`. To use the values of these properties in a pipeline, you must map the properties to pipeline parameters. After mapping the properties to parameters, you can access the values captured by the trigger through the `@pipeline.parameters.parameterName` expression throughout the pipeline. ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger#map-trigger-properties-to-pipeline-parameters))

You could get the filename and pass it into your stored procedure. Then do the deletion and copy activities.

Comment: Good idea Jay! But how to relate @company to the @triggerBody().filename parameter? Not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I you use the stored procedure activity you can fill the parameters from pipeline parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure

[image: ADF stored procedures]

You can click on "Import" to automatically add the parameters after selecting a stored procedure or add them by hand. Then you can use a pipeline expression to dynamically fill them, e.g. as suggested by Jay Gong using the trigger parameters  `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName`.

Alternatively, instead of using a stored procedure, you could add a pre-copy script to your copy activity:

[image: Pre-copy script]

This shows up only for appropriate sinks, such as a database table. You can fill this script dynamically as well. In your case, this could look like:

```
@{concat('DELETE FROM table 
WHERE [company] = ''',triggerBody().fileName,'''')}
```

It might also make sense, to add a parameter to the pipeline containing the filename, and setting it to `@triggerBody().fileName` or any more complex expression, in case you are using it multiple times.